# Using the OR operator (|) in jsonpath-ng python

Tags: python, json, operators, jsonpath

I have a json structure (client_json) that looks like:

```
client_json = { "data": [ { "attributes": { "creators": [ { "name": "This is a person", "nameType": "Personal", "givenName": "the", "familyName": "person" }, { "name": "This is an organization", "nameType": "Organizational", "givenName": "the", "familyName": "organization" } ] } } ] }
```

I am trying to use jsonpath-ng 1.4.3 (https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng) to retrieve creator names.

```
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse
```

These two expressions give the expected results:

```
[match.value['name'] for match in parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType='Personal')]").find(client_json)]
[match.value['name'] for match in parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType='Organizational')]").find(client_json)]
```

I am trying to combine them with an or operator and all of these expressions yield parse errors:

```
parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Organizational' | @.nameType == 'Personal')]")
parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Organizational' || @.nameType == 'Personal')]")
parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Organizational'), ?(@.nameType == 'Personal')]")
parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Organizational') || ?(@.nameType == 'Personal')]")
parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Organizational') | ?(@.nameType == 'Personal')]")
parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType = 'Organizational' | @.nameType = 'Personal')]")
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

In jsonpath we can apply filter for 'and' condition.

There is no such provision for 'or' condition.

This is what I have came to conclusion after trying lots of ways to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this same problem. I got success using the regex option. Your expression would then become:

`parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType =~ 'Organizational|Personal')]")`

Answer (score 0):

According to the rule *jsonpath1* `|` *jsonpath2*, this one goes without error:

```
[match.value['name'] for match in     
parse("data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Organizational')] | data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Personal')]").find(client_json)]
```

however returns only the second name of the two, i.e.

```
['This is a person']
```

contrary to what https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng says, that it should return a union.

Answer (score 0):

As written at source code [documentation](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/blob/master/jsonpath_ng/jsonpath.py) implementation is a little bit "shoddy"

```
class Union(JSONPath):
"""
JSONPath that returns the union of the results of each match.
This is pretty shoddily implemented for now...
```

So it only works on the same level objects "out-of-the-box", if you want to union complex independent expressions you need to help the parser with expression boundaries - just put parenthesis around your blocks.

E.g. the expression below

```
[match.value['name'] for match in     
parse("(data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Organizational')]) | (data[*].attributes.creators[?(@.nameType == 'Personal')])").find(client_json)]
```

should return both values

```
['This is an organization', 'This is a person']
```